# Using Knockout.js with CouchDB - updating when changed

Tags: couchdb, knockout.js

Just wondering about the best way to subscribe to my CouchDB data store, so that if a document in couch is updated, the KO view will also update (automagically). Is this something that's even possible?

Below is what I have so far, which simply get the user name from the user_info document.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/couchdb/user_info', function(data) {
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The viewmodel can be updated via JSON using the mapping plugin. see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

in you're case it will be ko.mapping.fromJS(data,this.ArrayOfModels) in the getJson callback

Comment: @Martijn, thanks for that, i've updated by original post. Although, this still doesn't quite solve the problem, as when the user_info document is updated (by another user, or something) that viewModel object doesn't get updated (other than through a page refresh)

Comment: You want to push data from the server to the client?  on a windows platform i would use setTimeOut to check for new updates regualry. However a very interesting project is nowjs ( http://www.nowjs.com/ ) If you have the possibility to use that platform you can write:

  now.receiveMessage = function (data) {
            ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewmodel, data);
        };

Comment: @Martijn, seems like i'll have to settle with setTimeout for the moment, as we've yet to migrate to a linux-based server. But NowJS is indeed exciting, as i've already been playing around with NodeJS for a bit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

CouchDB supports notifications when documents change: the [changes feed](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html).

You can poll the changes feed, with a `?since=X` parameter to receive only updates since X.

You can also "long poll" the feed by adding `&feed=longpoll`. If there are no changes yet, CouchDB will receive your query but not answer until finally a change comes on.

Or, you can have a full COMET-style feed by instead adding `&feed=continuous`. That is similar to longpoll, however CouchDB will *never* close the connection. Every time a change happens, it will send you the JSON and then continue waiting.

Finally, you can be notified when *anything* changes in the database, or you can specify a Javascript filter to run on the server (`&filter=designdoc/filtername`). You will only receive notifications if the filter approves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i'm pretty happy with the CouchDB side of things (having played around with it for a while). Curiously, i've never been able to quite get the continuous feed working, but am using the longpoll method. I was more after some information on the Knockout side of things, and seeing if the model could be updated automatically when it's source (CouchDB) is changed. I've already written code to do this manually though.

Thanks for the detailed post though!

Comment: The most likely reason the continuous feed wouldn't work is that the clientside library you are using to read it doesn't give you back a value until the server response is *complete* — by definition &feed=continuous is *never* complete.

Comment: Good point, and while I'm not a front-end expert, my understanding is that the only way to work with a partial response is by using XMLHttpRequest directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://hood.ie/ it woks well. I'm also running hoodie as an os_daemons service from within my couchdb.

It's nice.